# Dim CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), TextBox) as Textbox Publicly

Tags: vb.net

I have a tab control, which holds tab pages that have 1 text box in each of them. I have 2 buttons that change the selected tab page's text box to the text "Hello World."

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), TextBox).Text = "Hello World."
End Sub
```

When I try to dim the text box control as text 1 at the top of the class,

```
Dim text1 As TextBox = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), TextBox)
```

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147467261   Message=Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.   Source=HelloWorld   StackTrace:
>          at HelloWorld.frmMain..ctor() in E:\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\Form1.vb:line 6   InnerException:

I get this error because the tab page, with the text box is created when the form loads.

```
Dim tbTab = New TabPage()
Dim tbTextbox = New TextBox()

tbTab.Controls.Add(tbTextbox) 'Adds text box to new tab page
TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tbTab) 'Adds new tab page to tab control
```

So my question is how can I dim text1, publicity like you do on top of class

```
Dim text1 As TextBox = CType(tcTabs.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), TextBox)
```

after the tab page has been created, so I don't get errors. I want to be able to make the buttons do

```
text1.Text = "Hello World."
```

without having to dim text1 on each sub.

Comment: Simply declare the `text1` at the form level `Private text1 As TextBox` and assign `text1` a value in the the form's `Load` event handler, or wherever it is that you create the `TabControl` and the `TextBox`.

Comment: The TextBox and TabControl and TabPage do not exist yet where you are trying to reference and use them